# Matrix with all off-diagonal elements equal 1

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials, nilpotence

Consider the matrix, of size $n \times n$, of the following form:
\begin{bmatrix} a_1 & 1 & \cdots & \cdots1\\ 
1 & a_2 & 1 &\cdots 1\\
\vdots & 1 & a_3 &\cdots 1\\ 
 & \vdots & 1 & \ddots a_n & \\ \end{bmatrix}
I must prove this assertion
The matrix is nilpotent if and only if the $a_i -1$ are the zeros of the polynomial $P_n = X^n + (X^n)' + (X^n)'' + \cdots +n!$.

(For example, $P_4 = X^4 + 4X^3 + 12X^2 + 24X + 24$).

I have no idea how to approach this question. Could you help me? It seems that this property is not known see [link](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/348962/what-are-known-properties-of-matrices-where-off-diagonal-elements-are-1/348987#348987?newreg=a1acefb319524f0d822c9bbe9ce1e587)

If we vote to close it, that's your right.

Comment: Have you played around with the $2 \times 2$ case?

Answer (score 1):

Let $d_i=a_i-1$ and $D=\operatorname{diag}(d_1,\ldots,d_n)$. The matrix is then $D+ee^T$ where $e$ is the vector of ones. Hence its characteristic polynomial is
$$
\begin{aligned}
p(x)
&=\det(xI-D-ee^T)\\
&=\det(xI-D)-e^T\operatorname{adj}(xI-D)e\\
&=\prod_{i=1}^n(x-d_i)-\sum_{i=1}^n\prod_{j\ne i}(x-d_j).\\
\end{aligned}
$$
Write
$$
\prod_{i=1}^n(x-d_i)=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^kc_{n-k}x^{n-k}
$$
where $c_n=1$ and $c_{n-k}=\sum_{i_1<i_2<\cdots<i_k}d_{i_1}d_{i_2}\cdots d_{i_k}$. Then
$$
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{i=1}^n\prod_{j\ne i}(x-d_j)
&=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}
(-1)^k\sum_{\substack{i_1<i_2<\cdots<i_k}\\ i_1,i_2,\ldots,i_k\ne i}d_{i_1}d_{i_2}\cdots d_{i_k}x^{n-1-k}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(-1)^k
\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{\substack{i_1<i_2<\cdots<i_k}\\ i_1,i_2,\ldots,i_k\ne i}d_{i_1}d_{i_2}\cdots d_{i_k}x^{n-1-k}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(-1)^k(n-k)c_{n-k}x^{n-1-k}.\\
\end{aligned}
$$
Hence
$$
\begin{aligned}
p(x)
&=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^kc_{n-k}x^{n-k}
-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(-1)^k(n-k)c_{n-k}x^{n-1-k}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^{n-k}c_kx^k
-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(-1)^{n-1-k}(k+1)c_{k+1}x^k\\
&=x^n+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(-1)^{n-k}\big[c_k+(k+1)c_{k+1}\big]x^k.\\
\end{aligned}
$$
That $D+ee^T$ is nilpotent is equivalent to $p(x)=x^n$, which in turn is equivalent to $c_k=-(k+1)c_{k+1}$ for $k=n-1,\,n-2,\ldots,0$. Since $c_n=1$, the latter recursive relation is equivalent to $c_{n-1}=-n,\,c_{n-2}=n(n-1),\,c_{n-3}=-n(n-1)(n-2),\ldots$ etc.. Hence it is equivalent to the condition that $c_{n-k}x^{n-k}=(-1)^k\frac{d}{dx^k}(x^n)$, or that
$$
\prod_i(x-d_i)
=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^kc_{n-k}x^{n-k}
=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{d}{dx^k}(x^n).
$$

Comment: Great proof, thank you very much

Comment: If the matrix is nilpotent, I believe the nilpotence index is n.

Answer (score 1):

First follow either @user1551's answer or work slightly harder with elementary row operations, we get that $$\det(xI-A)=\prod_{i=1}^n (x-d_i) - \sum_{i=1}^n\prod_{j\not=i} (x-d_j)$$

Let $p(x):=\prod_{i=1}^n (x-d_i)$, then $$\det(xI-A)=p(x)-p'(x)$$
The matrix $A$ is nilpotent iff its characteristic polynomial is $\det(xI-A)=x^n$, therefore we have to show $p(x)-p'(x)=x^n$ iff $p(x)$ is the given polynomial $q(x):=x^n+(x^n)' + (x^n)'' + \cdots$

The $\Leftarrow$ direction is trivial by verifying $q(x)$ satisfies the differential equation. For $\Rightarrow$ direction, note that the first order linear ODE has general solution $p(x)=q(x)+Ce^x$ since $q(x)$ is a known special solution. Because $p(x)$ is a polynomial, $C$ has to be $0$, and $p(x)=q(x)$. (Or the differential operator $D$ is nilpotent on the space of polynomials of degree $\le n$, hence $(I-D)$ is invertible and $p(x)=(I-D)^{-1}x^n$ is unique.)